# Python subprocess.Popen with a variable setting

Tags: python

A friend of mine wrote to me a Python script that launch Photoshop with wine, using `subprocess.Popen`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess, re, sys, signal

error_keywords = re.compile('^.*(Assertion|0x65372a0).*$')
success_keywords = re.compile('^.*(list_manager_QueryInterface).*$')

exited = False
process = None
successful_launch = False
timeout = 3

def kill_photoshop(signalnum, frame):
    if not successful_launch:
        print("No successful launch withing %d seconds, killing photoshop ..."%timeout, file=sys.stderr)
        process.kill()

signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, kill_photoshop)

while not exited:
    process = subprocess.Popen(["wine64", "/home/artik/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop CC 2019/Photoshop.exe"], stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    successful_launch = False
    signal.alarm(timeout)
    while True:
        if process.poll():
            break
        line = process.stderr.readline()
        # print("got line %d and process %s"%(len(line),process.poll()))
        if len(line) == 0 and process.poll() is not None:
            if process.poll() == 0:
                exited = True
            break
        if line:
            print(line.strip())
            if success_keywords.match(str(line)):
                print("Successful photoshop launch detected", file=sys.stderr)
                successful_launch = True
            if error_keywords.match(str(line)):
                print("Error keyword match, killing process", file=sys.stderr)
                process.kill()
                break
    print("Process return code %d"%process.wait())
```

Since few days a bug is fixed, adding a setting to the wine launch command. The old line:

```
wine64 "/home/artik/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop CC 2019/Photoshop.exe"
```

And the new one:

```
__GL_MaxFramesAllowed="1" wine64 "/home/artik/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop CC 2019/Photoshop.exe"
```

So I have to add `__GL_MaxFramesAllowed="1"` to my process. I tried adding a variable in the script:

```
my_env = __GL_MaxFramesAllowed="1"
```

I tried

```
process = subprocess.Popen(["wine64", "/home/artik/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop CC 2019/Photoshop.exe"], env=my_env, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

But doesn't work. How to fix it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `env` parameter to `Popen` must be a mapping (i.e. a dict).

In addition, you'll probably want to copy your current environ and add to it:

```py
import os

# ...

# Copy current `os.environ` and add what's needed:
env = dict(os.environ, __GL_MaxFramesAllowed="1")

subprocess.Popen(..., env=env)
```

Comment: Thanks! in the meanwhile I fixed it changing: `import os` `os.environ['__GL_MaxFramesAllowed'] = "1"` and `env=os.environ`

Comment: note that if you're altering `os.environ` then this will automatically get passed to child processes (e.g. by subprocess) so you don't need to pass `env=env`

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to launch from the CLI using the same command manually? If not, I would suggest getting that working first, then convert that into Python.

Answer (score 0):

another option would be to exec the [`env` program](https://linux.die.net/man/1/env), i.e. your launch line would be:

```py
PHOTOSHOP = "/home/artik/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop CC 2019/Photoshop.exe"

process = subprocess.Popen(
  ["env", "__GL_MaxFramesAllowed=1", "wine64", PHOTOSHOP],
  stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

but doing it natively in Python is probably better!